# i deleted some code in my shopify store and now images pop up with this

Tags: shopify

im just lost on how to solve. also on chrome it says in console "Each dictionary in the list "icons" should contain a non-empty UTF8 string field "type".""

also a new code box comes up on shopify saying "

" and it is called "icon-unavailable"

ANY HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED

Comment: Please can you provide further details so we can help? Specifically: which file did you edit, attach a screenshot of the issue, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can open your code editor in Shopify, navigate to file that you have edited and there is a version history dropdown at the top. Choose the version before the change and you should be safe:

[image]